# Is Joiner thread safe?

Tags: java, thread-safety, guava

Is google collections Joiner thread safe?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Its only state is a

```
  private final String separator;
```

So yes it's threadsafe.

Comment: @Pangea - It's threadsafe now.  If it is not documented as threadsafe, that may change in the future.

Comment: Also, since it's such a cheap object to create, why not create it locally when needed?  Avoid sharing it between threads to begin with.

Comment: @Robin, that's prudent advice. Though documented or not, it would be awfully sociopathic of any library maintainer to change a class from threadsafe to not threadsafe after it's been released! We won't do that to you.

Comment: @kevin Bourrillion - Thats good to hear. Of course I have met a few developers that might fall into that sociopathic category as well  8-)

Answer (score 29):

Yes!  We're not about to repeat the mistakes of `SimpleDateFormat`. :-)

`Joiner` needs to receive a similar documentation upgrade to what its sister class `Splitter` got, which says:

```
* <p><b>Warning: splitter instances are always immutable</b>; a configuration
* method such as {@code omitEmptyStrings} has no effect on the instance it
* is invoked on! You must store and use the new splitter instance returned by
* the method. This makes splitters thread-safe, and safe to store as {@code
* static final} constants . . .
```

Comment: Joiner doc has been fixed now.
http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html